# Manual RewriteRules for individual pages followed by a catch-all for other pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a set of RewriteRules in my .htaccess file for specific pages, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpagename\.html$ /newpagename/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^anotheroldpagename\.html$ /newpagetwo/? [L,R=301]
```

There is no common structure to the redirects.

These work fine, but then there are still a large amount of other pages which I want to do a catch-all redirect to the homepage.

What rule do I need to add? I've tried a few that I've found on stack, but they all redirect everything to the homepage (ignoring the ones above).

Comment: Please do not ever so vaguely hint, _that_ you tried something, but _show_ what you tried.

Comment: Assuming that your definition of “page” is, the requested URL path ended with `.html`, then something simple like `RewriteRule \.html$ /? [L,R=301]` should probably do the trick already. (Placed _after_ the more specific rules, of course.)